# Gulp not creating JS files on live server

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, browserify

I have gulp installed on my project.

Locally, everything works fine when I run `gulp scripts:dev` it creates the file `bin/min.js`.

However, when I run the same task on the production server it doesn't create the `bin/min.js` file, but when running the whole gulp it successfully creates `bin/min.css`.

I have the same version of gulp, node and npm locally and on the server.

Here is my task :

```
gulp.task('scripts:dev', ['cleanJs'], function() {
    return browserify({ entries: './scripts/main.js', debug: true })
        .transform(babelify, {"presets": ["es2015"], "sourceMaps": true})
        .on('error', handleErrors)
        .bundle()
        .on('error', handleErrors)
        .pipe(source('min.js'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write("."))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./bin/'))
        .pipe(gulpif(global.livereload, livereload()));;
});
```

Here is my `scripts:prod` task that is also not working (the one I actually want but that is not creating the file either.)

```
gulp.task('scripts:prod', ['cleanJs'], function() {
    return browserify({ entries: './scripts/main.js', debug: false })
        .transform(babelify, {"presets": ["es2015"]})
        .bundle().on('error', handleErrors)
        .pipe(source('min.js'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./bin/'));
});
```

Comment: Why on production it calls `babelify.configure()` but no in dev? Did you try to use the same api in prod?

Comment: @Sergeon Nice find! But it's doing the same and doesn't solve the problem...

Comment: Did you ever try to catch and log errors after `gulp.dest('./bin/')`in production? It could be a permissions issue with `gulp` not having permissions to write the files.